# Adding a newly created Maven SNAPSHOT into another project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Help,

I've created my first maven snapshot jar file. I've uploaded it to my Git repository (In Target directory) Now I want to use the jar file in another project. How do I enable the maven dependency in my new eclipse project? As for my groupID was not sure how to create that since I'm doing this on my own.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.firstName.LastName</groupId>
<artifactId>bichromate</artifactId>
<version>0.1.1 SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven downloads dependencies from a centralized location and puts them into target/lib.  Accessing dependencies from this folder will only be overwritten when `mvn clean install` is run again.

I highly suggest you do a `mvn deploy` to deploy your artifact to a number of maven compatible artifact stores.  Sonatype Nexus, jFrog Artifactory, etc are designed to host your artifacts for use in gradle and maven project builds.

If you performed a `mvn clean install` of the dependency on your local machine, it will be in the `~/.m2/repository` or your local repository location.  In which case you can reference the artifact as normal.

Group ID's are typically the domain name of the company or persons releasing the artifact.  Artifact ID is the name of the artifact (of course).

If you want to include jar's locally (i.e. part of your project, from say a lib folder) then you'll want to use something similar to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/sample.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: can I run the maven deploy from within Eclipse? Or must I run that from the cmd Line.  As for groupID can I just change that in my pom file. instead of "firstName.lastName" and create a domain like "GringoGolf" ?

Comment: most ide's support maven commands, so yes.  However, if you haven't configured a repository to deploy to, it won't work.  `mvn clean install` will install it to your local user's repository or you can use my method described above to reference a jar locally.  Group ID's generally follow the form of a domain name backwards, so if you have one, use that.

Comment: I checked all my Maven projects here and none of them has a `target/lib` directory in it. It's neither mentioned in [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) nor in [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), too. Isn't it that Maven downloads to the _local_ repo (`~/.m2/repository`) and builds a classpath for the builds with artifacts from there?

Comment: Thank you again for the support. I was reading about the MOJO should that be part of my maven jar file. What is the use of the MOJO @GabrielReiser Again thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer has most of the important information, but I'll add a little more.

If it's not obvious, your git repo is not a valid place to store Maven artifacts. An artifact repository like Nexus and the others are what you need for a real system.

The reference in the first answer to "~/.m2/repository" is a reasonable "short-term" solution, just to verify for yourself that this dependency arrangement will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help